# Laravel scope query only for users - exclude result for admin

Tags: laravel, scope

I am very new into programming and trying to make some work on Laravel / Voyager.

I have a Customers table and on this table there is also Customer_Representative field where I can select / assign customer representatives from dropdown list.

What I am trying to achieve is I want each users with their assigned roles (Customer Representative) to list customers only assigned for them.

I am using this below code, but I am not able to see list of customers that other users created. 
I can only see the customers I / Admin created but If I login with their details I can see their assigned customers.

So as an admin I want to be able to see all customers, so I can also edit them with my login credentials.

```
 public function scopeCurrentUser($query)
    
    {
       return $query->where('Customer_Representative', Auth::user()->id);
    }
```

I saw many suggested to use if but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Appreciate your supports !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to display:

- admin users - all users
- non-admin users - only assigned users

You can either change the query in controller, but if you want to do it in scope I suggest something like this:

```
public function scopeCurrentUser($query)
{
   return $query->when(auth()->user()->is_not_admin, function ($q) {
      $q->where('Customer_Representative', auth()->user()->id)
   });
}
```

You change the **auth()->user()->is_not_admin** to your condition for non-admin validation. The scope utilizes the **->when()** function to append the condition to query only if the condition (in this case if authenticated user is not an admin) is true.

So if authenticated user is not an admin, his query will be filtered by Customer_Representative.

Comment: Hello @Lukas Grofcik, Thank you for your very quick reply / help. I do appreciate it very much. As I said I am very new into programming and I am using Laravel with Voyager admin panel and trying to customize backend according to my needs.

I tried your code but result is like this ;

syntax error, unexpected token "}"

I will be posting the code of the app with a new reply and try to explain it further.

Comment: semi-colon was missing in the code thats why I was getting error but this code didnt work for me. Still all users can see all customers details - I want each customer representative to see his own customers - and I want admin to see all customers.

Comment: @ hi Lukas, thanks for your help ! I changed code like this ;


   public function scopeCurrentUser($query)
    {
        return $query->when(auth()->user()->role_id === 3, function ($q) {
            $q->where('Customer_Representative', auth()->id());
        });
    }

role_id 3 is representatives - the ones which are not admins. so now admin with role_id 1 can see everything - and representatives can see their own customers only.